# using shell commands how to extract field from command (zdb)

Tags: shell, awk, freebsd, zfs

I need to [expand/resize a ZFS](https://fabrik.red/post/zfs-resize/) disk but for this, I need to extract the `children[0] guid` from the output of `zdb`, the current output looks like this:

```
root@:/ # zdb
zroot:
    version: 5000
    name: 'zroot'
    state: 0
    txg: 448
    pool_guid: 14102710366601156377
    hostid: 1798585735
    hostname: ''
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 14102710366601156377
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 12530249324826415927
            path: '/dev/gpt/disk0'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 38
            metaslab_shift: 24
            ashift: 12
            asize: 1066926080
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 36
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 37
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
```

For automating this process and putting all the steps in a shell script, I came up with this:

```
zdb | grep -A4 "children\[0" | grep guid | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'
```

Which returns:

```
12530249324826415927
```

Putting all together script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

DISK=`gpart list | head -n 1 | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'`
GUID=`zdb | grep -A4 "children\[0" | grep guid | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'`

gpart recover ${DISK}
gpart resize -i 3 ${DISK}
zpool online -e zroot ${GUID}
zfs set readonly=off zroot/ROOT/default
```

This is working but would like to know if there is a better way of extracting the fields without need to pipe too much, I am doing this on a raw [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) setup in where the root/zpool is read-only so I can't install python, bash, etc, I am bound to use only the basic stack within `/usr/bin` like cut, awk, sed, etc.

Would be nice if I could get the values directly from the commands like [zdb](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zdb&manpath=FreeBSD%209.1-RELEASE) but since haven't found a straight way of doing it I need to do some shell kung-fu.

Any tips, suggestions for improving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with a standalone `Awk` as below,

```
zdb | awk '/children\[0\]/{flag=1; next} flag && /guid:/{split($0,arr,":"); print arr[2]; flag=0}'
```

If a leading whitespace is worrying *someway* remove it using the `sub()` function as `sub(/^[[:space:]]/,"",arr[2])` as

```
zdb | awk '/children\[0\]/{flag=1; next} flag && /guid:/{split($0,arr,":"); sub(/^[[:space:]]/,"",arr[2]); print arr[2]; flag=0}'
```

The idea is to identify the patter `children[0]`, enable a flag and the next matching `guid:` is matched *only* when the flag is set. This avoids processing of lines with `guid:` is repeated more than once and skip them. The flag is reset when the first match is identified.

And do not use back-ticks for command substitution ever, use the more efficient way using `$(..)`

Comment: how good/bad is to split using `split($0,arr,": ")` notice the space after the `: `, the idea is to avoid the sub and remove the whitespace?

Comment: @nbari: It is a great idea!